# Cómo sumar valores de una lista anidada en Python?

Tags: python, lista, bucles

Tengo una lista anidada conformada por dos sublistas, a cada uno tengo que sumar y por ultimo promediar el valor de cada lista, también tengo que guardar el resultado en una lista nueva, para este caso el resultado correcto seria este: (resultado = [3.0 , 7.0]),

ahora mi problema en mi ejemplo es que el resultado se acumula de la primera sublista se acumula con la segunda.

```
numeros = [[1,2,3,4,5],[5,6,7,8,9]]
for x in range(len(numeros)):
    print("Lista ",x+1)
    for l in range(len(numeros[x])):
        suma += notas[x][l]
    promedio = suma / 5
    resultado.append(promedio)
print("resultado=: " , resultado)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un problema es que escribiste notas en vez de números en la suma y otro es que al termina cada ciclo debes restablecer suma a cero.

```
numeros = [[1,2,3,4,5],[5,6,7,8,9]]
resultado=[]
suma=0

for x in range(len(numeros)):
    print("Lista ",x+1)
    for l in range(len(numeros[x])):
        suma += numeros[x][l]
    promedio = suma / 5
    resultado.append(promedio)
    suma=0
print("resultado=: " , resultado)
```

Answer (score 2):

Una solución con comprensión de listas:

```
proms = [sum(sublista) / len(sublista) for sublista in numeros]
```

Esto crea una lista con los promedios de las sublistas. Esta es una forma compacta de escribir:

```
proms = []
for sublista in numeros:
    proms.append(sum(sublista) / len(sublista))
```

**Demo**

```
numeros = [[1,2,3,4,5],[5,6,7,8,9]]
proms = [sum(sublista) / len(sublista) for sublista in numeros]
print(proms)
```

produce:

```
[3.0, 7.0]

Process finished with exit code 0
```